# SUM of Multi Columns with group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a big complex query with 40+ column. The result of the query look like this:

| itemCode | itemName | customerCode | customerName | fac1 | fac2 | sum(fac2) | fac3 | sum(fac3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | ABCD | 0023 | Dummy 1 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.75 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
| 001 | ABCD | 0024 | Dummy 2 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.75 | 0.2 | 0.5 |
| 001 | ABCD | 0025 | Dummy 3 | 0.50 | 0.25 | 0.75 | 0.2 | 0.5 |
| 002 | EFGH | 0023 | Dummy 1 | 0.20 | 0.52 | 0.52 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 003 | MNOP | 0023 | Dummy 1 | 0.50 | 0.75 | 1.25 | 0.3 | 0.7 |
| 003 | MNOP | 0024 | Dummy 2 | 0.20 | 0.50 | 1.25 | 0.4 | 0.7 |

I want the individual values (i.e fac columns) and SUM of some of these columns (like column sum(fac2) above). The problem here is that the sum should be group by itemCode and not with all values (not with customer code as well). I don't mind sum values repeated in sum(fac2) or sum(fac3) columns. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a Windowed `SUM`; they were supported in SQL Server 2008 (which has been *completely* unsupported for 3 years now, and you really should have migrated off it by no)..

Comment: That's a specification, not a question.

Comment: Your data structure also seems to be lacking normalization with repeating columns.

Comment: It is actually not a table but the result of a very complex query getting data from different tables and calculations............... what I want to ask is how can I get the value on sum(fac2) and sum(fac3) column??? ... (P.S. I have done the normalization)

Comment: among us among us

Answer (score 0):

I got it through below:

```
sumFac2 = SUM(fac2) OVER (PARTITION BY itemCode)
```